# Check if --upgrade was passed during pip install

Tags: python, github, arguments, setup.py

In my setup.py file, I would like to check whether `--upgrade` was passed in `pip install ...` and if so I would like to run some code.

In this example "Hello World" should only print if `--upgrade` was passed during pip install otherwise nothing should happen.

```
# setup.py

setup(...)

if "--upgrade was passed": # WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE
  print("Hello World")
```

So if I ran `pip install package-name` the if statement would return false, but if I ran `pip install --upgrade package-name` the if statement would return true and the code inside it would run.

Comment: I don't know if it can get this information but first I would use `print()` to see what it gets in `sys.argv`

Comment: The results were the same for both `--upgrade` and not were the same, so no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not possible. (And this is on purpose.)

The `setup.py` is not always executed when `pip install YourProject` is run (most commonly it is the case when installing from a pre-built *wheel*: the setup script is not executed since wheels do not even contain the setup script). And when *pip* does trigger the execution of `setup.py`, it is quite indirectly and *pip*'s arguments are very unlikely to be forwarded to `setup.py`. One way I know of to somehow let *pip* forward arguments to `setup.py` is to (mis)use [*pip*'s `--global-option`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-global-option).